# sendpfast ERROR: while trying to exec [None]: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scapy, tcpreplay

I am trying to replay a file using scapy's sendpfast function. But it throws an error.

```
a = rdpcap("U:\\Tests\\pcaps\\test1000.pcap")
sendpfast(a)

ERROR: while trying to exec [None]: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I am using windows 7 with scapy 2.3.3. FYI: I haven't installed TCPreplay separately. Is this because of that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install `tcpreplay`, as Scapy won't do that for you (and it is required to use `sendpfast()`).

Comment: any ideas how to do that on windows, as I couldn't find any method to install it on windows platform.

Comment: No idea. You should ask another question, so that someone can see it and help you.